# Why I´m getting this error using barplot in Rstudio "incorrect number of names"?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I´m trying to make a barplot for ancestry in Rstudio, an got the error "incorrect number of names"

This is the code I run:

```
# Cargar los datos
datos <- read.table("admix.txt", header = TRUE)

# Definir los nombres de las poblaciones
Poblacion <- c("America","Europa","Eurasia","EurAm","Europasia")

# Crear el gráfico de Admixture
barplot(t(as.matrix(datos[, -(1)])), col = rainbow(ncol(datos)-1), 
        xlab = "Individuo", ylab = "Proporción", names.arg = Poblacion)
```

My dataset:

```
Poblacion   origen1 origen2
America 0.006666    0.993334
America 0.779961    0.220039
America 0.427611    0.572389
America 0.813640    0.186360
America 0.652604    0.347396
America 0.499865    0.500135
America 0.290712    0.709288
America 0.447847    0.552153
America 0.840954    0.159046
America 0.523092    0.476908
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.143286    0.856714
America 0.472235    0.527765
America 0.771131    0.228869
America 0.511068    0.488932
America 0.025474    0.974526
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.005296    0.994704
America 0.685525    0.314475
America 0.418856    0.581144
America 0.653668    0.346332
America 0.225173    0.774827
America 0.383285    0.616715
America 0.058886    0.941114
America 0.009342    0.990658
America 0.015007    0.984993
America 0.002664    0.997336
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.145986    0.854014
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.015244    0.984756
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.000010    0.999990
America 0.167392    0.832608
America 0.640400    0.359600
EurAm   0.000648    0.999352
EurAm   0.255487    0.744513
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.450210    0.549790
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.546981    0.453019
EurAm   0.484598    0.515402
EurAm   0.086021    0.913979
EurAm   0.285348    0.714652
EurAm   0.031093    0.968907
EurAm   0.069430    0.930570
EurAm   0.037918    0.962082
EurAm   0.022321    0.977679
EurAm   0.320998    0.679002
EurAm   0.106400    0.893600
EurAm   0.048877    0.951123
EurAm   0.182298    0.817702
EurAm   0.031725    0.968275
EurAm   0.312833    0.687167
EurAm   0.457584    0.542416
EurAm   0.054852    0.945148
EurAm   0.553960    0.446040
EurAm   0.002580    0.997420
EurAm   0.025126    0.974874
EurAm   0.999990    0.000010
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.147882    0.852118
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.221932    0.778068
EurAm   0.181649    0.818351
EurAm   0.595149    0.404851
EurAm   0.681347    0.318653
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.702988    0.297012
EurAm   0.000010    0.999990
EurAm   0.002774    0.997226
Eurasia 0.005494    0.994506
Eurasia 0.000010    0.999990
Eurasia 0.019013    0.980987
Eurasia 0.019751    0.980249
Eurasia 0.023125    0.976875
Eurasia 0.335525    0.664475
Eurasia 0.019229    0.980771
Eurasia 0.028028    0.971972
Eurasia 0.000010    0.999990
Eurasia 0.667998    0.332002
Eurasia 0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.021506    0.978494
Europa  0.085614    0.914386
Europa  0.002423    0.997577
Europa  0.136019    0.863981
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.001705    0.998295
Europa  0.008959    0.991041
Europa  0.005611    0.994389
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.011926    0.988074
Europa  0.685324    0.314676
Europa  0.026084    0.973916
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.016599    0.983401
Europa  0.007035    0.992965
Europa  0.132058    0.867942
Europa  0.005673    0.994327
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.007433    0.992567
Europa  0.022336    0.977664
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.076555    0.923445
Europa  0.205925    0.794075
Europa  0.023510    0.976490
Europa  0.003213    0.996787
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.020198    0.979802
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.174797    0.825203
Europa  0.130237    0.869763
Europa  0.128710    0.871290
Europa  0.015761    0.984239
Europa  0.016476    0.983524
Europa  0.016811    0.983189
Europa  0.000863    0.999137
Europa  0.162520    0.837480
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.004684    0.995316
Europa  0.019208    0.980792
Europa  0.492487    0.507513
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.015666    0.984334
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.018586    0.981414
Europa  0.228070    0.771930
Europa  0.054701    0.945299
Europa  0.015723    0.984277
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.147377    0.852623
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.015433    0.984567
Europa  0.194324    0.805676
Europa  0.142146    0.857854
Europa  0.181220    0.818780
Europa  0.003677    0.996323
Europa  0.355231    0.644769
Europa  0.402608    0.597392
Europa  0.067520    0.932480
Europa  0.171952    0.828048
Europa  0.014737    0.985263
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.003896    0.996104
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.795202    0.204798
Europa  0.006578    0.993422
Europa  0.021397    0.978603
Europa  0.145587    0.854413
Europa  0.062430    0.937570
Europa  0.000010    0.999990
Europa  0.012280    0.987720
Europa  0.999990    0.000010
Europa  0.020080    0.979920
Europa  0.134631    0.865369
Europasia   0.023057    0.976943
Europasia   0.000010    0.999990
Europasia   0.016871    0.983129
Europasia   0.058525    0.941475
```

origen 1 and 2 are the proportions of ancestry for each individual obtained with admixture

I tried the code I showed you above,
I expect this:
[image: stacked plot in R]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Poblacion` vector is only of length 5, `barplot` does not know that you want `names.arg` to be repeated correctly per each individual. May I suggest that you use `ggplot2` instead?  This may not be the most efficient or elegant solution but it gets you a few steps closer to what you want.

I read in your data and called it `df`.

```
#install these packages if you don't already have them installed
library(forcats)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df$Poblacion <- factor(df$Poblacion)
df$ID <- as.numeric(row.names(df))

#reshape the data set for ggplot
melt.df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("ID","Poblacion"), value.name = "percentage")

#this is to reverse the factor levels because there is a problem with ordering 
#geom_bar and legends that is too involved to describe here
melt.df$reassigned.origen<-"origen1"
melt.df$reassigned.origen[melt.df$variable=="origen1"]<-"origen2"

melt.df$ID <- as.numeric(melt.df$ID)
melt.df$reassigned.origen <- factor(melt.df$reassigned.origen)

#> head(melt.df)
#  ID Poblacion variable percentage reassigned.origen
#1  1   America  origen1   0.006666           origen2
#2  2   America  origen1   0.779961           origen2
#3  3   America  origen1   0.427611           origen2
#4  4   America  origen1   0.813640           origen2
#5  5   America  origen1   0.652604           origen2
#6  6   America  origen1   0.499865           origen2

#this is for labeling the x axis; it calculates the median ID per region
ID.medians <- aggregate(ID ~ Poblacion, data = melt.df, summary)

ggplot(data=melt.df) +
#plot a stacked bar that sums to 100%; it looks strange but 
#gets the percentages and levels in the right order
  geom_bar(aes(x=ID, y=percentage, fill = forcats::fct_rev(reassigned.origen), 
               color=Poblacion), stat="identity") +
#this removes the title for the legend
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
#adds the regions at the x axis
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ID.medians$ID[,3],
                     labels = levels(ID.medians$Poblacion), minor_breaks=NULL) +
#labels for x and y axes
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage origen1")
```

This is what I get:
[image: First draft of ggplot for geneology]

You will likely have to do quite a bit more work with colors, factor levels, and formatting. Hopefully this will get you started though.